# Network Node Traffic Prediction Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, regression

I need to build a regression model for next N days of a network node.

My dataset contains following features:

YYYYMMDD info ; day of week (which affects traffic) ; Customer count on that node ; is it holiday or not ; and 2 other parameters that also affects traffic.

Label : MBPS which is max traffic for that day in mbps metric.

I tried LinearRegression(), RandomForest(), SVR() , AdaBoostRegressor() and so many others but I couldnt even get a positive r2 score or acceptable MSE or MAE on those models.

Could you please help me to build a base model on this dataset so I can go for better by using hyperparameter tuning etc.

My goal is find a matching model and generate N days ahead predictions.

Thanks

Sample Dataset:

```
"YEAR_I","DAYOW_I","CST","IS_HDAY","MATCH_COUNT","PRIORITY","MBPS"
"20190620","5",167,0,0,0,826279
"20190624","2",169,0,0,0,775120
"20190625","3",168,0,0,0,753918
"20190626","4",168,0,0,0,807338
"20190627","5",168,0,0,0,739691
"20190628","6",168,0,0,0,844546
"20190629","7",162,0,0,0,691837
"20190630","1",162,0,0,0,754769
"20190701","2",162,0,0,0,903428
"20190702","3",161,0,0,0,856882
"20190703","4",158,0,0,0,767688
"20190704","5",158,0,0,0,779772
"20190712","6",150,0,0,0,710226
"20190713","7",156,1,0,0,764292
"20190714","1",153,1,0,0,848846
"20190715","2",154,2,0,0,904547
"20190716","3",154,0,0,0,750170
"20190717","4",153,0,0,0,734258
"20190718","5",154,0,0,0,845613
"20190719","6",157,0,0,0,779454
"20190720","7",156,0,0,0,728447
"20190721","1",153,0,0,0,684583
"20190723","3",151,0,0,0,849301
"20190724","4",151,0,0,0,765968
"20190725","5",151,0,0,0,739072
"20190726","6",150,0,0,0,755601
"20190727","7",155,0,0,0,772812
"20190728","1",155,0,0,0,731838
"20190729","2",155,0,0,0,834939
"20190730","3",153,0,0,0,702836
"20190731","4",152,0,0,0,726787
"20190801","5",152,0,0,0,724125
"20190802","6",153,0,0,0,764430
"20190803","7",148,0,0,0,831460
"20190804","1",148,0,0,0,658365
"20190805","2",143,0,0,0,755955
"20190806","3",142,0,0,0,711848
"20190807","4",142,0,0,0,624254
"20190808","5",143,0,0,0,754606
"20190809","6",141,0,0,0,637655
"20190810","7",134,1,0,0,658406
"20190811","1",130,3,0,0,613327
"20190812","2",124,3,0,0,592067
"20190813","3",124,3,0,0,614577
"20190814","4",125,3,0,0,662439
"20190815","5",130,0,0,0,717342
"20190816","6",137,0,1,2,826435
"20190817","7",141,0,3,2,972885
"20190818","1",140,0,4,2,722316
"20190819","2",142,0,1,2,797723
"20190820","3",147,0,0,0,957704
"20190821","4",146,0,0,0,759117
"20190822","5",144,0,0,0,737167
"20190823","6",149,0,1,2,776062
"20190824","7",148,0,3,1,744867
"20190825","1",148,0,4,2,818992
"20190826","2",149,0,1,3,833498
"20190827","3",152,0,0,0,772883
"20190828","4",149,1,0,0,824638
"20190829","5",143,1,0,0,868814
"20190830","6",149,2,2,2,792668
"20190831","7",149,0,3,2,830225
"20190901","1",152,0,4,1,841708
"20190902","2",156,0,0,0,829972
"20190903","3",153,0,0,0,893880
"20190904","4",153,0,0,0,821667
"20190905","5",152,0,0,0,909714
"20190906","6",152,0,0,0,869165
"20190907","7",152,0,0,0,709631
"20190908","1",152,0,0,0,775142
"20190909","2",152,0,0,0,867715
"20190910","3",152,0,0,0,791050
"20190911","4",152,0,0,0,820059
"20190912","5",159,0,0,0,814888
"20190913","6",79,0,0,0,850085
"20190914","7",157,0,0,0,791931
"20190915","1",156,0,9,2,749324
"20190916","2",154,0,0,0,853970
"20190917","3",157,0,0,0,798672
"20190918","4",159,0,0,0,820866
"20190919","5",158,0,0,0,847518
"20190920","6",160,0,0,0,898552
"20190921","7",161,0,0,0,806703
"20190922","1",158,0,9,1,803148
"20190923","2",165,0,0,0,828497
"20190924","3",163,0,0,0,958130
"20190925","4",162,0,0,0,911552
"20190926","5",160,0,0,0,827984
"20190927","6",156,0,0,0,811705
"20190928","7",160,0,0,0,845845
"20190929","1",160,0,9,1,841719
"20190930","2",160,0,0,0,811585
"20191001","3",162,0,0,0,817447
"20191002","4",162,0,0,0,990958
"20191003","5",160,0,0,0,880470
"20191004","6",48,0,0,0,910185
"20191005","7",158,0,0,0,900281
"20191006","1",157,0,9,2,824448
"20191007","2",158,0,0,0,1014439
"20191008","3",161,0,0,0,845978
"20191009","4",163,0,0,0,795588
"20191010","5",159,0,0,0,888827
"20191011","6",161,0,0,0,898451
"20191012","7",159,0,0,0,864003
"20191013","1",161,0,0,0,793733
"20191014","2",160,0,0,0,778911
"20191015","3",0,0,0,0,844110
"20191016","4",158,0,0,0,877697
"20191017","5",159,0,0,0,880386
"20191018","6",155,0,0,0,960184
"20191019","7",118,0,0,0,885271
"20191020","1",130,0,9,2,853794
"20191021","2",155,0,0,0,959543
"20191022","3",162,0,0,0,948837
"20191023","4",162,0,0,0,874080
"20191025","6",159,0,0,0,841795
"20191026","7",155,0,0,0,840083
"20191027","1",155,1,9,1,882195
"20191028","2",155,1,0,0,804998
"20191029","3",155,2,0,0,873209
"20191030","4",149,0,0,0,851670
"20191031","5",156,0,0,0,825803
"20191101","6",156,0,0,0,944468
"20191102","7",163,0,0,0,882644
"20191103","1",163,0,9,2,877474
"20191104","2",163,0,0,0,801663
"20191105","3",163,0,0,0,861581
"20191106","4",163,0,0,0,880810
"20191107","5",162,0,0,0,852350
"20191108","6",162,1,0,0,917474
"20191109","7",161,1,0,0,864701
"20191110","1",162,2,9,2,879234
"20191111","2",165,0,0,0,873829
"20191112","3",165,0,0,0,801106
"20191113","4",165,0,0,0,871859
"20191114","5",162,0,0,0,947029
"20191115","6",161,0,0,0,829755
"20191116","7",161,0,0,0,894351
"20191117","1",161,0,0,0,806946
"20191118","2",161,0,0,0,927961
"20191119","3",161,0,0,0,908957
"20191120","4",165,0,0,0,897570
"20191121","5",164,0,0,0,840253
"20191122","6",162,0,0,0,917120
"20191123","7",162,0,0,0,889958
"20191124","1",163,0,9,1,866761
"20191125","2",161,0,0,0,872199
"20191126","3",159,0,0,0,997972
"20191127","4",161,0,0,0,889243
"20191128","5",161,0,0,0,815678
"20191129","6",165,0,0,0,894917
```

Answer (score 0):

For time series, better use ARIMA if you know what you are doing, and Prophet if you don't ;)